# What is the result of effecting permutation $(124)$ on $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, permutations

[This](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/10/16/permutations/) article claims:

> we simply replace the number 1 by 2, the number 2 by 4, and the number 4 by 1
>
> ....I start with the numbers arranged as follows: 1 2 3 4 5 6. After doing the permutation (124) the numbers are arranged as 2 4 3 1 5 6.

I always thought $(124)$ was read left to right as "1 goes to 2, 2 goes to 4, and 4 goes to 1" and therefore the outcome should be 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6.

According to my understanding, the article did the permutation reading from right to left. Is the blog following a convention of reading right to left, or do I just have it wrong?

Comment: I don't know what convention is more accepted, but I read permutations from left to right.

Comment: The key fact here you have to replace all them *simultaneously* in one step, not step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better example would be:

If you apply the permutation $(1\,2\,4)$ to (each element of) the sequence "6, 5, 3, 1, 2, 4" you get "6, 5, 3, 2, 4, 1".

The 6, 5, and 3 are unchanged by the permutation, 1 becomes 2, 2 becomes 4, and 4 becomes 1.

Comment: Ok thanks I see the mistake have always thought that "1 goes to 2" means that "1 is now in the place where 2 was" so "2 becomes 1"

Comment: "(to each element of)" was also enlightening

Comment: @Ovi: No, you're still reading it backwards. "1 goes to 2" means the same thing as "1 becomes 2", namely that we're talking about a function $f$ such that $f(1)=2$. So when you're seeing $1$ in a particular place of the input, you write $f(1)$, which is $2$, in that particular place of the output sequence.

Comment: @Ovi: It's the difference between replacing the sequence $(a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ with either $(f(a_1), f(a_2), \ldots, f(a_n))$ or $(a_{f(1)}, a_{f(2)}, \ldots a_{f(n)})$.

Answer (score 5):

The text says "Let me illustrate this with $n=6$ and those two permutations. I start with the numbers arranged as follows: 1 2 3 4 5 6. After doing the permutation $(124)$ the numbers are arranged as 2 4 3 1 5 6." So indeed $1$ goes to $2$, and $2$ goes to $4$, and $4$ goes to $1$, if you read this top-down:
$$
\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\cr 2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 6\end{matrix}
$$

Comment: So is the author following the convention of reading right-to-left? Or is he reading left-to-right but I just misunderstood left-to-right reading when I learned it?

Comment: No, not right-left is the problem, but top-down - see above.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be reading it as saying "1 goes to position 2", but the convention is that it should be read as "1 gets replaced by 2", or "object 1 becomes object 2". It helps to view these permutations in an alternate form (where for each number, we write the image underneath).
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$$
If we think of having the numbers in front of us as physical objects, laid out in order, after applying the permutation to these objects $2 \ 4 \ 3 \ 1 \ 5 \ 6$ is what we will see in front of us.

Answer (score 1):

The third paragraph states that:

> $\ldots$ If we want to apply the permutation $(124)$, we simply replace the number $1$ by $2$, the number $2$ by $4$, and the number $4$ by $1$ $\ldots$.

Following the rule (reading from left to right), gives us the required result.

Comment: So is the author following the convention of reading right-to-left? Or is he reading left-to-right but I just misunderstood left-to-right reading when I learned it?

Comment: @Ovi It is just the plain replacement of the required numbers.